# wordpress custom latest post functions code issue

Tags: wordpress, function

I am using this code in `function.php` for latest posts:

```
function last_article($atts){
$a = shortcode_atts( array(
    'posts' => 1,
), $atts );
$q = new WP_Query(array('orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC' , 
'posts_per_page' => 1 , 'category__in' => $atts ));
if ($q->have_posts()) { 
  while ($q->have_posts()) { 
     $q->the_post();
     $return_string .= '<div class="content"><div class="thumb">'.featured_image_thumb().'</div>';
     $return_string .= '<h2><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></h2>';
     the_excerpt();
     $return_string .= '<div class="detail"><div class="data"><span><i class="icon-user"></i>'.the_author().'</span><span><i class="icon-calendar"></i>'.the_time('j F  Y').'</span></div>';
     $return_string .= '<div class="more"><a href="'.get_permalink().'">more... <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></a> </div></div></div>';
  }
} 
wp_reset_postdata();  return $return_string;  }
```

And then use `echo last_article` in theme.
But it first show featured image and then shows `<div class="content">` empty. and also shows some other HTML tags empty.

Can someone tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function last_article($atts){
$a = shortcode_atts( array(
    'posts' => 1,
), $atts );
$q = new WP_Query(array('orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC' , 
'posts_per_page' => 1 , 'category__in' => $atts ));
if ($q->have_posts()) { 
  while ($q->have_posts()) { 
     $q->the_post();
     $return_string .= '<div class="content"><div class="thumb">'.featured_image_thumb().'</div>';
     $return_string .= '<h2><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></h2>'
     . get_the_excerpt()
     . '<div class="detail"><div class="data"><span><i class="icon-user"></i>'.the_author().'</span><span><i class="icon-calendar"></i>'.the_time('j F  Y').'</span></div>';
     $return_string .= '<div class="more"><a href="'.get_permalink().'">more... <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></a> </div></div></div>';
  }
} 
wp_reset_postdata();  return $return_string;  }
```

Comment: unfortunately the result is same

Comment: could you provide a screenshot?

Comment: this is inspect screenshot, as you can see image comes first and then class thumb comes empty http://uupload.ir/files/6zkk_111.png